# Supporting auto property of menu-props (Vuetify.js)

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

In [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#caveats), it is mentioned that

> The auto property of menu-props is only supported for the default input style.

I'm not sure what it means by "**default input style**", since I couldn't find/create an instance that the auto property of menu-props isn't working as expected. Would you please tell me what it is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the sense in trying to look for a problem you don't have, but I did some research and found the warning was added to the VSelect documentation in v2.2.9 originally to address [this github issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10375)

It looks like this is the timeline of what happened:

1. User reported a problem with v-select which happened to use both the `filled` prop (non-default input style) and `:menu-props="{auto: true, overflowY: false}"`
2. Vuetify developer's first action is to add a warning to the documentation that menu-prop's auto attribute is to be used with default input style only. Issue is closed.
3. Second Vuetify developer re-opens the issue with the statement **"That has nothing to do with auto or default styles"**. The warning in the documentation is wrong!
4. There is a back and forth between developers and users to figure out the real problem/solution. Issue is eventually given up on and/or forgotten about.
5. Improperly added warning in the documentation is never removed. Issue is still technically open to this day, but is probably no longer an issue since the v3.0 overhaul.

In conclusion, you can ignore the warning in the documentation because it's incorrect.